# Asp.Net Core RC2 Web Api IIS Error 404

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, iis-7.5, .net-4.5.2, .net-core-rc2

I'm developing a Web API using ASP.NET Core RC2 with full framework (4.5.2). 
I have published in IIS using AspNetCoreModule but I get a 404 error when I call any method.
I checked that "Startup" class and this runs.

I think the problem is that the IIS is not working well like a proxy.

I publish the API with the assistant of VS2015.

This is my Program class:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your code work without IIS? Could you show the rest of your code?

Comment: Yes, my code work without IIS. Debugging with VS (run IISExpress) and works. I've created a new blank project with VS2015: file->new project->asp net application->Web API, I've published it and neither works. You can try and check.

Comment: The problem is the IIS configuration. If I publish the API like "Application" under a WebSite It doesn't work but if I publish like a "Web Site" it works. I need publish like "application" under a Web Site.

Comment: I have a similar issue and don't know how to solve it. What do you mean "publish like 'application' under a Web Site"? In IIS, after expanding the node for the server, we see the list of Sites. Under that, the only thing that can be added is a new Web Site.

Comment: No. Under a website you could add an "applicatiion". Right click on website.